# How do I make an accessible onClick handler for links in React?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, anchor

I have a link in my React application that calls an `onClick` handler as follows:

```
<a onClick={handleClick}>Link</a>
```

However, since I'm not using the native `href` attribute, this handler does not get activated when I focus the link, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, of course I could add an `onKeyDown` handler, then check whether the key that was pressed is <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and, if it is, call `handleClick`. However, I'm afraid that that won't be enough to capture all accessibility nuances, nor whether it will behave exactly like regular links.

Thus, the question is: is there a way to indicate that I want my function to be called when the link is followed by whatever possible interaction method?

Comment: Are you using React Router in your application ?

Comment: @reach/router, but in this case it's an actual `<a>` element, not a `<Link>`.

Comment: so why not using a `Link` ?

Comment: Because it's not a link to a different page in the application. It performs different actions depending on the current app state, ranging from making a GET request and updating the view depending on the response, to opening a pop-up.

Comment: Sounds like `<button>` would be a better fit?

Comment: It might, see my comments below the answers for why I didn't go with one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

an `<a>` tag without an `href` is no longer valid. Instead of trying to reimplement focus and keyboard logic, use a `button` and style however you like. Semantically, if it is firing an `onClick` it should most likely be a `button` and will be most accessible.

For reference https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md

Comment: Agreed, although one correction.  An <a> without an `href` **is** valid.  It's just not a link and is not a tab stop.

Comment: I'm guessing I should change it into a button (it currently is an `a[role="button"]`, which doesn't sound too logical a day later). Still, the question remains: do I still need to add my own `onKeyDown` handler? Or do I wrap it in a form and listen to `onSubmit`? Anything else?

Comment: `<a role="button">` is semantically correct - screen readers will _announce_ it as a button. BUT it also needs to _behave_ like a button, i.e. it needs to be operable with the spacebar as well as the return key. So yes, you do need a key handler to emulate this. By contrast, a HTML `<button>` is already set up to be operable by space-or-return, so you can just use the click handler for that. The browser knows that soace-or-return on a button is the same as a click. Use a button!

Comment: @vincent if you use a `<button>` it will handle onKeyDown for you

Comment: @JustH Cool, I did not know that and cannot find docs on it, but it appears to be true. That saves quite a bit of uncertainty, thanks!

Comment: @JustH Just found out that's not even React-specific, but works for buttons in general, which is great: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54073140/859631

Answer (score -1):

You have the right idea `onKeyDown` or something needs to be set.
Ideally I would recommend using a library like Microsoft's FabricUI or Material which do all of this behind the scenes.

Alternatively you can use react-a11y package which has checks for such things. Following is the check for onClick

https://github.com/reactjs/react-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/click-events-have-key-events.md

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll be going for adding my own keyDown handler then and hope I cover all the basis. I'd rather not adopt all the styling and such that come with things like Fabric or Material.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that react-a11y will give you warnings when your code is not a11y compatible. So instead of hunting for issues you will know exactly what to fix and where.

Comment: instead of relying on complex UI libraries, use semantic HTML and make the element a `button` and you get everything for free (minus having to reset styles)

Comment: Thanks @codebreach, I prefer to use a linter for that, but otherwise I agree with your point. Ideally, however, this would be fixed automatically rather than a warning telling me to do it manually.

Comment: @JustH That's what I'd prefer to do. Unfortunately, the element contains some other elements that, as far as I'm aware, don't really lend themselves well to a button. Using a button would also require me to embed it in a form and to handle the `onSubmit` event, no?

Comment: @vincent buttons can contain content and be styled freely. Buttons do not require a form.

Comment: @JustH I found out - not sure where that misconception came from. Instead, buttons cannot be a flex container, but I managed to work around that.