# Why does a `click` event get triggered on my <button> when I press Enter on it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility, dom-events

I'm only adding a `click` event handler on my `<button>`.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("Click:", event);
});
```

```html
<button>Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on me</button>
```

([Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jn0rk13oz9?expanddevtools=1))

Nevertheless, when I tab to the button in Firefox, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I see the `click` event being fired. However, I cannot see this behaviour documented anywhere. Is this standard behaviour, and can I count on it working in all browsers?

Comment: Try pressing the space bar when the button is in focus...another surprise..you clicked the button :-)

Comment: Hehe yeah I got that, left it out for brevity :)

Comment: keyboard geeks don't often use the mouse. Many even use vi-like addons to their browsers so that they can surf the web without ever touching their mouse. It's very frustrated when an app don't respond to keyboard events

Comment: @phuclv Blind users do *everything* using the keyboard. Some types of motor impairments also require keyboard access.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe blind doesn't only mean a complete vision lost. Many people with low eyesight do use a mouse with magnifier. And not only those, keyboard inputs are used a lot by other users. For example `tab` to move between form fields, and after filling them people will just press `enter` to submit instead of pressing the submit button with the mouse

Comment: @phuclv I have had fully blind colleagues. I know how they use the Web.

Comment: It's for historical reasons essentially. "Click" was always the name of the button-push event in Windows regardless of whether the button was pushed by mouse or by keyboard. If you need to distinguish them you can use "keyDown" and "mousedown". Click is a "cooked" event i.e. synthesized by the system. The "raw" events are mousedown, mouseup, keydown, keyup etc. Usually raw events are left to default behaviour which results in the "cooked" event, because that corresponds more directly to what programmers generally care about.

Comment: @phuclv Perhaps not coincidentally, I'm one of those using a vi-like add-on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is largely because lots of authors have historically written code using click events while forgetting to account for users who don't click (whether because they prefer to use a keyboard to navigate, have a disability which makes it hard to use a pointing device, or whatever other reason).

The behaviour is [documented in the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#activation):

> Certain elements in HTML have an activation behavior, which means that the user can activate them. This triggers a sequence of events dependent on the activation mechanism, and normally culminating in a click event, as described below.
>
> …
>
> For accessibility, the keyboard’s Enter and Space keys are often used to trigger an element’s activation behavior.

It then goes on to explain the steps in detail.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the reference - I will be relying on that for accessibility then!

Comment: It's a very useful mechanism. If you plan to rely on it for accessibility, the caveat is that most elements do *not* have this default behaviour, so if you're using (say) a div or a span as a control, you'll have to add the key event handling yourself. (Be sure to add a role attribute too!)

Comment: @brennanyoung — And make them keyboard accessible with tabindex … best to use elements designed to be interacted with in the first place!

Comment: Quite right. You get a lot of accessibility 'for free' with `<a>`, `<input>` and `<button>`, but otherwise `tabindex` is just as important. Unfortunately, a11y implementation is far too rarely considered 'in the first place'.

Comment: I switched from an `<a>` to a `<button>` for exactly this reason - to make sure I get the browser's a11y features for free. With `tabindex`, `role` and `click` and `keydown` event handlers, I'm sure I'd probably still have forgotten something, or would implement something incorrectly :)

Comment: *"This is largely because lots of authors have historically written code using click events while forgetting to account for users who don't click"* No it isn't, it was always like that from the very beginning of Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Because for keyboard users (where a mouse is not available), when a button is in focus and you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (possibly <kbd>Space</kbd> as well) it simulates a click event.

This is the browser's accessibility support which most, if not all, browsers provide.

Comment: "It's part of the ISO" — It isn't … and nobody uses ISO HTML anyway.

Comment: @Quentin Removed. You're right, our workplace puts a big importance on the ISO hence the reference.

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not mean "why did they make it this way", but "why did browsers implement this - was it because it was standardised, or because they thought it was a good idea themselves". Apparently the former!

Comment: @Vincent – The standard was defined after most browsers had already implemented it.

Comment: I see. Well, that's great for me - saves me implementing keypress handlers myself :)

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in WCAG: *[SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35.html)*:

> While `onclick` sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button. The default action occurs when the user clicks the element with a mouse, but it also occurs when the user focuses the element and hits <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd>, and when the element is triggered via the accessibility API.

This is also stated in [UIEVents /click section](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#click):

> In addition to being associated with pointer devices, the `click event` type **MUST** be dispatched as part of an element activation, as described in §3.5 Activation triggers and behavior.

[The Activation trigggers paragraph](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow-activation) states that:

> User-initiated activation triggers include clicking a mouse button on an activatable element, pressing the <kbd>Enter key</kbd> when an activatable element has focus, or pressing a key that is somehow linked to an activatable element (a hotkey or access key) even when that element does not have focus.

Which means that any of those triggers will dispatch the `click` event.

Comment: Huh, that first excerpt is interesting - in an earlier test, the `click` event did not get triggered when I bound the listener to an anchor on which I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. See e.g. here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4r3rl2nrz7?expanddevtools=1

Comment: @Vincent In your example, your `a` anchor lacks an `href` attribute to make it a link. So the `a` tag will have no default action.

Comment: Ah, right. But then that first excerpt is, I think, about something else: clicking a button (or anchor) activates its default behaviour. Whereas the question was not about what happens when you click the button, but about why the `click` event is triggered when you _don't_ click the button. (Which I think the other two excerpts show.) Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using `div` element with onClick listener instead. It seems that `button` element captures enter press for the accessibility purposes, like the guys above wrote.